# PHPExcel $objWriter->save('php://output'); on php 7.0 ubuntu 16.04 not working

Tags: php, yii, ubuntu-16.04, phpexcel-1.8.0

Earlier on php 5.6 file  got saved.
After updating to php 7 and os to ubuntu 16.04.
It is not working

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('KYC Report');
                $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                //print_r($objPHPExcel);die;

                // Redirect output to a clientÃƒÂ¢Ã¢â€šÂ¬Ã¢â€žÂ¢s web browser (Excel5)
                header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                 // It will be called file.xls
                 //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sectionlist.xlsx"');
                if (Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Magicbus-admin') || Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Magicbus-accountant')) {
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Transaction Report"' . date('ymdhis', time()) . '.xlsx');
                } else {
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=KYCReport-"' . date('ymdhis', time()) . '.xls');
                }
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
                ob_end_clean();
                ob_start();
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
                Yii::app()->end();
```

I am using PHPExcel 1.8 on yii 1.Both php version are enabled on server ie. 5 and 7.

Comment: what error messages are you getting?

Comment: And "Not Working" means what exactly? Empty file? No file? File with incorrect data? Error messages? File containing error messages?

Comment: It doesn't give any error message. Throwing 500 error code. echo "hello" above   $objWriter->save('php://output'); working

Comment: Then check your logs, see what error messages are being written there

Comment: And look at what is being suppressed by your `ob_start();`

Comment: You could also try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` for debugging in the top lines of the script. Just don't forget to remove it afterwards.

Comment: this happens because php7.0-zip module is not installed. I solved it by installing that.

Comment: For me after installing `php5.6-zip` module it worked fine.